# Signals and Slots in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots, qt4.7

I'm trying to create a signal and slot in Qt4 and I am fairly new to Qt. From what I understand in Qt5 it is just created automatically and this is not the case in Qt4 it seems. I'm trying to create a an action when the user clicks on an option in the menu bar at the to of the UI.= I see that there is a Signal/Slot editor at the bottom of the screen with options "Sender", "Signal", "Receiver", and "Slot".  I'm not entirely sure how to use this function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation about signals and slots in Qt4?](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to connect your signal and slot

```
connect(ui->button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(yourSlot()));
```

and in this link there is good example about signals and slot: [signals and slots in qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood.

The difference in Qt 5 is that it offers new syntax to make the connections.

The connection is "automatic" when you don't specify the connection type, i.e. direct, queued, etc, the default is automatic, which makes Qt check the object's thread ownership and select the appropriate connection type.

Connections must either be explicitly made in code, or be made using the UI editor, and while the latter may save you some typing in some cases, in general most of the connections you end up making are explicit in code, so you better learn how to do it, because the UI editor can help you only in a few corner cases. I haven't really used the UI editor for connections, and have tried it once or twice years ago, but the limitation I think is that you can only make connections between UI elements and signals and slots of the widget.

Consider that signal and slot connections are not merely a UI thing, it is a core principle in Qt and UI is just one of its many uses.